# How does Full Text Search work with binary data types (such as varbinary and image)

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, varbinary

I was creating an application in which we have to store files in data base. So i have chosen **varbinary** for it. Now we need to configure **Full Text Search** on this column.

But I am able to understand how **varbinary** data type will handle FTS. Because **FTS works on text data type.**

Answer (score 3):

Check [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142499%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in MSDN

> To create a full-text index on a varbinary(max) column, the Full-Text Engine needs access to the file extensions of the documents in the varbinary(max) column. This information must be stored in a table column, called a type column, that must be associated with the varbinary(max) column in the full-text index. When indexing a document, the Full-Text Engine uses the file extension in the type column to identify which filter to use.