# How to get .docx files based on key words

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, .doc

I have a sql table with the columns "candidatename", "candidatelocation" and "resume".here resume column have only .docx type files in binary form. from front end I need to enter some words or phrases. My requirement  is to get all the records which contain these words(or phrases) in .docx file("resume" column).. Here I'm not getting that how to search the given words with the binary type column.. I need this using asp.net with c# and sql server

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter Binary data?

Comment: @Legends: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, didn't know that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712151/how-doest-full-text-search-works-with-binary-data-types-such-as-varbinary-and-i

Comment: storing .docx file in varbinary(MAX) type column in sqlserver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the Microsoft Filter Pack (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/945934) which will enable you to create a full text index on the varbinary column you are using to store the .docx document.